# Check if a cell B contains all the words in a cell A with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, split, google-sheets-formula, countif

I have a cell A2 that contains a string of text (eg: french cooking youtube channel). This is a dynamic cell as the input of this cell can change depending on the input of the user. 
What I want to do is to check if the cell B2 contains all  the words in A2. The order doesn't matter, what I want to see is if all of the words are present in the cell (eg: IF B2 contains youtube french channel cooking, it should be OK) 
So far, I have tried the following formulas, but they're not working:

```
=IF(RegExMatch(A2;B2);"YES";"NO")
=IF(ISTEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2; B2)); "Yes";"No")
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible ? If yes, how could I go about it ?
Thanks in advance! 
PS : here is a demo spreadsheet with the formulas I have tried so far: (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rEf_9rZSCf6RL9D44XN9Z7GGDwhQPxHdFDItXLgYh4M/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(FILTER(SPLIT(B2; " "); 
       NOT(COUNTIF(SPLIT(A2; " "); 
                   SPLIT(B2; " "))))<>""; "no"); "yes")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, it worked! 
Do you think that there is a way to have the same function, but to check if the text string of the cell B2 matches at least 50% of the text string in the cell A2?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jfVPNleRdkoMkFVLdxWV7iI8j6gRA6QFzA-vbfeg4RY/edit#gid=0